# Influx v1.8 CLI query gets Killed

Tags: influxdb

I'm looking at options to export data from InfluxDB to MySQL. I'm exploring the option to export the data to flat files for the import (so we don't have to hit our production InfluxDB instance).

When I execute the command `influx -database 'mydb' -execute 'SELECT * FROM "1D"' -format csv > my-influx-all.csv` it runs for about a minute and then outputs `Killed`.

My test DB is about 2.1GB in size atm so not large. The production DB is 51GB. Is there a flag I can pass so Influx CLI doesn't die? Or is there an alternate way to export data into a flat file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query you can might hit an OOM. Further details should be found in the logs.

If you want to export the data in an readable format, you could try [influx_inspect](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/influx_inspect/#export) :

```
sudo influx_inspect export -database yourDatabase -out "influx_backup.db"
```

Comment: Thanks. The export worked but the output was not what I expected.

Do you know how this export is ordered? For example we're putting data in with multiple fields using line protocol like `1d,userId=1 a=1,b=3,c=d <timestamp>` but the output seems to have split it out to one field per row.

We're inserting a million entries a day all with the same timestamp. So it's making it hard to correlate the fields with the particular row.

Comment: influx_inspect export should export all data in line protocol format and it's line by line. I tried on my side. Sample output is as follows: "# writing tsm data
air_condition_outdoor,home_id=0000000000001,sensor_id=0000000000089 battery_voltage=3.2 1514764800000000000
air_condition_outdoor,home_id=0000000000001,sensor_id=0000000000089 battery_voltage=3.1918452921941833 1514764860000000000
". As you can tell, each line protocol is separated with a carriage return.

Comment: I have quite a few fields that I'm entering with the line protocol format. For example something like: `outdoor,home_id=1 sensor_id=89,battery_voltage=3.2,temp=30.2,humidity=50.0 1514764800000000000` and we're writing about 5m data points with the same timestamp (batch job). The export above seems to split the fields to one per line and the tags aren't ordered. For example it outputs: `outdoor,home_id=1 sensor_id=89 15147648000
outdoor,home_id=3 battery_voltage=4 15147648000
outdoor,home_id=5 humidity=50.0 15147648000`. We're only using `sensor_id` as a field rather than a tag.

Comment: And each `home_id` has up to 15 or 20 sensors which has got me a bit confused cause the ordering is a bit all over the place

Comment: If you are only using **sensor_id** as a field instead of a tag, I would assume that for each line protocol, there is no tags at all. That means, for 5m data points with the same timestamp, you would end up with much less data (than 5m) because InfluxDB will merge and rewrite the data points if their timestamp and tags are the same. In your case, I would say, **home_id** and **sensor_id** should be a tag while **battery_voltage**, **temp** and **humidity** should be fields.

Comment: The way InfluxDB export data is to iterate all TSM files inside data directory and pipe them into line protocol format. See more details [here in the code](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/1.8/cmd/influx_inspect/export/export.go). Because TSM are organized based on time range and tag's hash. Thus the exported lines are not exactly in the order of writing order or time order. Nevertheless, it has all the data.